# How to copy paste a passage to a word document without the signature?

Tags: kindle

Kindle has this annoying feature where if you copy paste a passage (not to mention ctrl+c does not work...) a lengthy signature detailing the books title will be added when you paste the text.

Is there a way to remove this feature?

Comment: Please read the kindle tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That "feature", as you call it, is there for a few reasons:

- In many evolved countries, companies are mandated to prove they do
  their best to protect intellectual property rights and this is one of
  them.
- Another good reason is to provide a reference to their content should
  the reader be interested in buying it.

Comment: Yep! And help reduce people plagiarizing the material.

Comment: I bought the content, hence why I copy paste it from Kindle. Anyways, I like to make a synopsis of what I read in a word file and it makes my life hard :(

Comment: Bar:  That is understandable, but even if you bought it, you don't own any right to reproduce it unless that was explicitly mentioned (not the case here for sure).

Comment: Citing your source can actually protect you should you share that document with anyone.